# Are "Will" and "Would " interchangeable?

Tags: will-would

Consider this sentence I found online:

> "I am an extremely easy-going guy, and I think I would fit in with
>   almost anyone"

If I replace "would" with "will" in above sentence,what is the change in meaning?

Answer (score 1):

I think I will fit in with anyone.

I think I would fit in with anyone.

Both the sentences are grammatical, but there's a little difference in meaning.

In case of the former, you are more positive about what you think. With the use of will,  You are confident that you are able to fit in with anyone, whereas with the use of would, you indicate that there's a possibility of your being able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to Khan's answer, it goes a step further.

"I think I will fit in" implies you are are actively going forward to something and assuming you will fit in. "I think I would fit in" implies you think you would but aren't going to try, or, in this context, isn't actively going to try right now.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "aren't going to try"..why  would(or will?) not I be trying if i think there is a chance ?

Comment: There are many reasons, perhaps the person not wanting to try is afraid of rejection despite feeling like the risk is low. Another reason is maybe the feel they would fit in somewhere else but are happy where they are so do not feel the need for change. I have expanded on my answer above.